# How can I access to a dictionary element indexed with a string?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to access to an element of a dictionary with a string.
For example, I have a dictionary like this:

```
data = {"masks": {"id": "valore"}}
```

I have one string `campo="masks,id"` I want to split this string with this `campo.split(',')`. I obtain `['masks', 'id']` and with this I want to access to the element `data["masks"]["id"]`.

This dictionary is an example, my dictionaries have more complexity. The point is that I want to access to the element `data["masks"]["id"]` with an input string `"masks,id"`, or to the element `data["masks"]` with the string `"masks"` and to the element `data["masks"]["id"]["X"]` with the input string `"masks,id,X"` and so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: Inner dictionary's are not a problem http://ideone.com/23qiH3

Comment: Putting as a comment as not a proper answer: `a = data['{}'.format(c.split(',')[0])]['{}'.format(c.split(',')[1])]` `>a = 'valore'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, I won't recommend you to use the following method, as python `dict` is not meant to be accessed the way you want it to be, but since in Python you can change the object type at your own risk, I would like to attach the snippet which would get the work done for you.

So what I do is iterate over the keys and at each iteration fetch the child dictionary is present else put empty dictionary, the `.get()` method used, returns empty dict if the key was not found.

```
data = {"masks": {"id": "valore"}}
text = "masks, id"
nested_keys = text.split(", ")

nested_dict = data
for key in nested_keys:
    nested_dict = nested_dict.get(key, {})
    if (isinstance(nested_dict, str)):
        print nested_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you are coming up with requirements that do not match the capability of the python-built-in dictionaries.

If you want to have nested maps that do this kind of automated "splitting" of a single key string like `"masks, id, X"` then ... you will have to implement that yourself.

In other words: the answer is - the built-in dictionary can't do that for you.

So, the "real" thing to do here: step back and carefully look into your requirements to understand exactly what you want to do; and why you want to do that. And going from there look for the best design to support that.

From an implementation side, I think what you "need" would roughly look like:

- check if the provided "key" matches "key1,key2,key3"
- if so, *split* that key into its sub-keys
- then check if the "out dictionary" has a value for `key1`
- then check, if the value for `key1` is a dictionary
- then check if that "inner" dictionary has a value for `key2`
  ...

and so on.

Comment: I think I need a function that make this: campo=campo.split(',') if len(campo)==1 data[campo[0]] if len(campo)==2 data[campo[0]][campo[1]] .....

Comment: Sorry for my explanation, what I want is a function that requires a string, for example "key1,key2,key3" and with this, it could access to the element data[key1][key2][key3] of the dictionary data. I know the dictionary and I know which string pass to the function to get the value that I want, but I need how to write this expression data[key1][key2][key3] passing only "key1,key2,key3" to the function

Comment: And I gave you the steps required here. It is **your** product; so you should be doing the coding - because you will be responsible for maintaining it. Or, when you tried, and "it doesn't work"; then put up a true [mcve] and give specific explanations where your current code breaks. But this is not a place where you drop requirements and other people hand over "ready to use code". Well, it can happen; as it just did: but the point is: you should really learn to this **yourself**. I gave you all the things you need to solve it yourself!